# system freezes while watching video or after wake up

Tags: system

[image]Im new on elementary os. I quite like it so far but i have a serious issue. My computer freezes while watching videos or after wake up. I can only move the cursor but i cannot click not even with keyboard. So I turn of my pc by pressing the power button. There is no exsessive heat. I put my computers spec below. please help I'll have to install win7 if no one help me :(

Asus-X201EP
Dual-Core Intel® Celeron® CPU 847 @ 1.10GHz
1.9 GB memory
117.1 GB SSD storage

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: Please attach or include the output of `sudo lshw -C display` in the question to help others answer question.

Comment: As this might be an Intel driver issue (probably not elementary's fault), you could try asking on Ubuntu forum: https://askubuntu.com